# TomEE - Netbeans - folder outside project

Tags: netbeans, deployment, apache-tomee, tomee-7, netbeans-8.2

I'm using Netbeans 8.2. for JavaEE Webapp with a TomEE 1.7.xx Server. 
I need a folder with images, that is changed by the users.
Therefore I can't have the folder within in my project, because with war deployment it would be overwritten all the time with my development files.

Does anyone know how I can handle this?

Answer (score 0):

You could deploy another another empty web application next to your application.

If a user upload an image in your application you would write it into e.g.:

```
tomee/webapps/imagecontainer/images/
```

and reference it from inside your application

```
<img src="myDomain.com/imagecontainer/images/xyz.jpg"/>
```

Like this you can deploy anytime any new version of your application. Of course
you are not allowed to undeploy the imagecontainer application.